# jquery set counter within the function which is called by itself

Tags: jquery, function, counter, jquery-callback

I try to make a counters of correct and incorrect given answers.
The count happens within the if else construction after the user clicks on the button.

```
(function keerSom(){


//generate and put a random number between 1 and 10 
a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
$(".a").html(a);

//get the variable b
b = $(".b").text().trim();

//get the cursor inside the input field and set the input field clean
userInputBox.focus();
$("#userAnswer").val("");


//make the calculations and check
next.click(function() {

$("form").submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});

result = a*b;
userInput = $("#userAnswer").val();


//check if the answer was correct
if (result == userInput){
userInputBox.removeClass("incorrect");
userInputBox.addClass("correct");
//set count of correct 
correct++;
$("#correct").html(correct);
```

If the answer is correct I need to move on to the next task for the user (this means back to beginning of the function)

```
//go for anothe som
 setTimeout(function(){
 userInputBox.removeClass("correct");
 keerSom();
 }, 3000);
}else{
userInputBox.addClass("incorrect");
//set counter of incorrect
incorrect++;
$("#incorrect").html(incorrect);
userInputBox.focus();
}

});
```

})();

You can see what I'm trying to do here http://jsfiddle.net/pmjmny49/9/

The problem is that the counter works wrong. It counts in a progression, it adds not 1 but 2,then 4 and so on.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Surely it is because of the calling back the function inside itself... but I don't see what can I do to make it work.

If someone can help, explain what's going on, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would honestly separate the `keerSom()` function from the click handler as you are getting a recursion. Each time you click the next button the the function runs as many times as it has been applied to the button, which is a multiplier of how many times you've clicked the button. A separation of these two will prevent that from happening. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmjmny49/13/)

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;

var userInputBox = $("#userAnswer");
var next = $("#next");

var keerSom = function () {

    //generate and put a random number between 1 and 10 
    a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $(".a").html(a);

    //get the variable b
    b = $(".b").text().trim();

    //get the cursor inside the input field and set the input field clean
    userInputBox.focus();
    userInputBox.val("");

};

keerSom();
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

next.click(function () {

    var result = a * b;
    var userInput = userInputBox.val();

    //check if the answer was correct
    if (result == userInput) {
        userInputBox.removeClass("incorrect");
        userInputBox.addClass("correct");

        //set count of correct 
        correct++;
        $("#correct").html(correct);

        //go for another
        setTimeout(function () {
            userInputBox.removeClass("correct");
            keerSom();
        }, 500);

    } else {
        userInputBox.addClass("incorrect");
        //set counter of incorrect
        incorrect++;
        $("#incorrect").html(incorrect);
        userInputBox.focus();
    }

});
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed separation of the click event made it work properly. :-) But I still want to understand better the original problem. It has to do with binding more than one event with the button... I have posted the "answer" below.

Comment: Could you probably give a hint where the case like I have is good explained? Would you call it recursion?

Comment: Check this out. This is essentially what you were doing before: http://jsfiddle.net/xakdgdzk/1/

Comment: Thanks a ton! You've helped me out! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your setInterval, you call a the keerSom function, which has a binding funciton, that means that a dom may be binded twice or more just for one kind of event. A solution is to unbind all event before you rebind the event

```
setTimeout(function(){
 userInputBox.removeClass("correct");
   next.unbind(); 
 keerSom();
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `keerSom()` it binds events on the elements. Just isolate the question generation logic and don't bind more and more events on the same button each time you reload the question.

Here is a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pmjmny49/10/

P.S. There is another answer that suggests unbinding event from the button and then rebind it again after reload. This is an option too, but while you have one static button and one static field - save resources and don't bind/unbind event each time you answer new question.

Best

Comment: Thank you for helping! Actually it's a pity that I cannot choose more than one helping/best answer...  I would like to learn more about the problem I have created.  I still don't quiet understand the mechanism of what's happening. Could you give a me hint where I can find more info on that?